# Anybody using Rhino Security?

Tags: security, rhino-tools

If so, what is your experience?

Do you recommend it?

This is the one I am talking about
http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/22/Rhino-Security-Overview-Part-I.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I recommend it if you are using NHibernate. It simplifies the whole process.

The only good resource as source code that I found is:
[weblogs.asp.net/arturtrosin/archive/2009/04/02/rhino-tools-rhino-security-guide.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/arturtrosin/archive/2009/04/02/rhino-tools-rhino-security-guide.aspx)

But this is not complete. I am looking for some more examples. 
The author's blog: [ayende.com/Blog/category/548.aspx](http://ayende.com/Blog/category/548.aspx)

One example for web projects, the link to the source is in the comments:
[bartreyserhove.blogspot.com/2008/10/integrate-rhino-security-with-aspnet.html](http://bartreyserhove.blogspot.com/2008/10/integrate-rhino-security-with-aspnet.html)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I am using it in a mixed LLBLGen and nHibernate scenario for a complex MVC site. It works great but getting it running the first time is a royal P-I-T-A.

The biggest issue, so far, is that I cannot use the same transaction for both nHibernate Sessions and LLBLGen Sessions. I have to run separate transactions/sessions and commit one before starting the other.

I've also run into several bugs and fixing them is up to you. No one seems to be maintaining the code any more.